# WiX with database MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database, wix, wix3.5

I am going to make wix with database MYSQL, i have searched in google.
[Connect to mysql](http://code.dblock.org/Showpost.aspx?id=100) example from wix. After i used code from that, i had error. The DataSource:ODBCExecute element contains an unexpected attribute 'File'.

and my question are: is that right ? Do you have another option to make wix generate script to mysql. 
Thank you everyone.

Comment: The link you a using: http://code.dblock.org/Showpost.aspx?id=100 describes connecting to MS SQL server. The arguments for MySQL are very different from this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ODBCExecuteFile`, [look here.](http://code.dblock.org/Source/msiext/1.2/Docs/class_wix_1_1_extensions_1_1_data_source_1_1_o_d_b_c_execute_file.html)